# How to do online/offline sync with a ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, offline, offline-caching, offline-browsing, web-storage

Is there any way to do offline syncing with a rails project?

In other words, our client is using their site to show a photo gallery, but they need to be able to do it without an active internet connection. At any time, they can get back online - and download any new data - to be able to continue showing their gallery?

Thanks!

Comment: You could check out rack-offline by Yehuda Katz. https://github.com/wycats/rack-offline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to use rack-offline, but no one answered it.

It can be found at [github](http://github.com/wycats/rack-offline) if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make a javascript client application, that stores changes and state inside the HTML5 local storage. So for the user he can do actions, which can be saved/synced later to the server (e.g. when he is connected to the internet again).

Sproutcore would be ideal for this. I am not sure if any of the up and coming javascript libraries (Backbone.js, spine.js) interact with local storage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't help that sproutcore.com is throwing a 503 atm :)